# Why i can't handle error connection? MQTT

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt

I am trying to handle two cases. When the connection is successful and not. I created a promise that should return if the connection is successful. But it does not handle the error (the connection does not work at all (I think the problem is authorization)). 
If I enter the wrong username or password, then the connection does not work at all.
I need to handle the error, any ideas?
UPD. Body server.on is not called if i using wrong password or username. I think its feature mqtt connect or something.

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  server = mqtt.connect('url', {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'pass'
  });
  server.on('connect', (res) => {
    resolve(true);
    server.end();
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you closing the connection if it succeeds `server.end()` after the `resolve(true)`?

Comment: Also the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) lists all the events the mqtt client object emits, there are more than just  `connect`...

Comment: I just check if I can join the broker (link, login, password), then return the status and close the connection. This is all I need, but I cannot handle the error (not a valid password, for example)